# How to reset menu in GNOME 3?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, menu

I have ubuntu 11.10 with Gnome3 shell DE. I have a problem, in the applications menu i can't find some applications like GParted, Update-Manager, gnome-tweak-tool that they can be run from terminal. I know that i can add launcher, but i don't know how many other applications aren't show!

I have already proved this solutions:
[How do I reset GNOME to the defaults?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults)
but it doesn't work.

In Unity everything is ok, can you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved this problem by deleting .local and .cache folder from my home.