# Compiz stop working

Tags: unity, compiz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I reset GNOME to the defaults?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults)

I'm on a laptop sony vaio, vng-nw330f with ubuntu 11.10.

One day I used my computer normally, I shutdown and the other day when I turn on it again, all was different. Compiz effects is not working at all, it doesn't matter what plugin (from ccsm) i enable or disable, nothings happens, nothings changes.

I tried next commands:

```
unity --reset
unity --reset-icons
sudo rm -rf .config .gnome .gnome2 .gnome2_private .compiz .icons .fonts .nautilus .themes .qt .local (from my home directory)
gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1
```

I try reinstalling compiz (I remove compiz from software center and installed it again).

I have just a couple of weeks using ubuntu, I'm not sure if exist a desktop call it unity 3d, but I think that it's missing.

I want the graphics interface of ubuntu 11.10 by default.

Comment: Have you tried removing ~/.compiz-1 ?

Comment: I did it now and reboot, but still not working.