# Compiz configuration/settings are not working

Tags: 12.04, compiz, graphics

I've made some changes to my compiz with `compizConfig settings manager`, like enable the cubic desktop and changing the unity icons size.

Today when I started my laptop, they all where gone back to default and I can't even change it back. I mean when I change them in compizConfig, they are not changed in reality, no effects.

I've restarted once, and no effect. Also updated and upgraded packages. `compiz --replace` and `unity --reset` didn't work.

And yesterday I installed cheese and gparted. Maybe it was because of that. And this is the first time in my life I'm seeing this.

My question is very similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80779/compiz-stop-working) . Had a look at the bugs in compiz launchpad, didn't find anything matching.

Some info about my laptop:

```
alfred@alFitop:~$ uname -a
Linux alFitop 3.2.0-24-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 21 16:52:17 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

alfred@alFitop:~$ compiz --version
Compiz 0.9.7.8

alfred@alFitop:~$ unity --version
unity 5.12.0

alfred@alFitop:~$ Xorg -version
X.Org X Server 1.11.3
Release Date: 2011-12-16
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.24-31-server x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux alFitop 3.2.0-24-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 21 16:52:17 UTC 2012 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic root=UUID=404922f4-7e8b-42a4-b009-a03aabb8aa24 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Build Date: 07 May 2012  11:43:21PM
xorg-server 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.24.4
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.

alfred@alFitop:~$ lspci -nnk | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0046] (rev 12)

alfred@alFitop:~$ sudo lshw -C Video
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 12
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:41 memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:1800(size=8)
```

(I wasn't sure what to put, if you think any of the info is unnecessary, feel free to edit and remove that part and save other's time :D )

Comment: I don't have this problem anymore, made a clean install.

Answer (score 1):

Most of that info is useful.  I just now hit something similar after accepting automatic updates.  Not sure exactly what was in the list of packages updated.

I finally fixed the problem via unity --reset.  In other words login under Unity, then ctrl-alt-f6 to get to a terminal, log in, and run unity --reset.

I dislike the solution because I am left not knowing which of the many settings needed to be tickled.  But sometimes it's better just to start from scratch and apply your tweaks forward.

Here's the article I read that convinced me to try it:
[Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Not sure if it will help your situation, but I was in exactly the same situation.

HTH