# Black frame around screen after HDMI connection failure

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, resolution

I was trying to watch a movie in my computer through the TV, so I connected both with an HDMI cable. I was unable to have a successful setup (the colors were all weird on the TV and the screen size, incorrect), I tried many resolutions using the `nvidia-settings` application and somehow my screen got framed by a black border and after that I have been unable to remove it, even after restarting the computer and not being connected to the HDMI cable anymore.

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 amd64, my GPU is an nVidia GeForce 8600M GT and I am using the propietary driver version 280.

The problem is due to some setting with my account only. I logged in to the guest session and the resolution is right there.

Also, my desktop "thinks" the resolution is right (i.e. 1280x800), but it must be right in another scale because there is pixel area occupied by the black frame.

Comment: have you tried the reset "gnome 3" settings as per this Q&A? http://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out finally, I removed the `.nvidia-settings-rc` file on my home directory and the problem was fixed :)