# Can't install GNOME Shell extensions from the extensions.gnome.org site

Tags: gnome, extension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Not able to install extensions from official website](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87772/not-able-to-install-extensions-from-official-website)

When I go to [extensions.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org/) to add shell extensions to my Ubuntu 11.10 box I am getting a notification that **I don't have an up to date version of GNOME Shell**.  however, I installed the version that I have now from the Ubuntu repositories just today.  Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: I had a similar problem on my desktop's 11.10 partition, so I can at least confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with the extension site. I get the same message in Chrome. Try the site in Firefox and it should work fine.