# Unity freezing on login. How to reset?

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)
>   [How do I reset GNOME to the defaults?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults)

Upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10 failed. Reinstalled 11.10 without formatting. Appears that config files in /home are breaking Unity (because it runs fine from a live CD). Cannot run 'unity --reset' as the graphics corrupt, the mouse freezes and it appears the keyboard is frozen as well. How can I repair this from recovery mode?

Comment: You might want to try this.. - http://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults

Comment: @JorgeCastro Might it be wise to have a separate canonical question for "unable to login"? While this post calls it "freezing", I think it's a different sort of problem (eg calls for revert configs rather than TTYs and REISUB). And most people I do not think would search for it with that set of words.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by doing similar steps to the comment by @jrg. If you are wary of deleting too many things, you can try deleting some of the Gnome settings files at a time.

- When light-dm seems to freeze on log-in, you can hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, log in, and run the commands from @jrg's comment ([Reset Gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults))
- Then run:

  ```
  sudo killall light-dm
  sudo light-dm
  ```
- And log back in.