# login to account reverts to login screen, guest login ok

Tags: login, guest-session

When I get to the login screen, I put my password, and I only get a black screen for 2 seconds, then we're back at the login screen. When I log in to the guest account everything works perfectly.

What I've tried;
I deleted .Xauthority as per instructions from elsewhere. No luck
I removed 2 lines I put in .profile. No change
Installed Gnome, but Unity, Unity 2D, various vers of gnome, same thing.

according to other q/a's, this could be caused by lack of disk space. I have 80 gigs free, so I would assume it's not that

if I Ctrl+Alt+F2 at login, I can login in to my account in the "terminal" with no problem.
I would really appreciate any help to restore my account, and thank you very much beforehand

Comment: try to read this http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword

Comment: what version of Ubuntu and what window manager ? Probably a corruption in one of the configuration files, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults

Answer (score 2):

It works perfectly now. I decided to examine my `.profile` file again, and I discovered a rogue apostrophe at the end of the last line. I must have grazed the <kbd>'</kbd> button when I input those 2 lines, that I removed later. Delete that and everything is good. Thank you for helping me.

PS. using 11.10

Comment: If this post solved your problem, please accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change owner for these files: `.Xauthority` and `.profile`, exist in your /home directory. see bellow for example.

Press alt+ctrl+f2, you'll be prompt on terminal, now log-in same user account in which you facing problem and use these commands:

```
ls -lha
sudo chown username:username .Xauthority
sudo chown username:username .profile
```

Where `username` is that username which you need to login.