# I can't use my own account but I can access guest accounts

Tags: guest-session

I am a new to intermediate user who has logged on here/at stack exchange as eimi and another means which I don't have record of now. My security is compromised, I believe. I get a blank desktop as if there is a screen over my main login desktop. I guess my question is this - how do I get to my sudo account via a guest terminal? What do I type at guest-PeoYMo@phi-ETMN-7:~

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The guest session is prevented by design to access regular accounts.

One thing you can do is opening a console window using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and log in from there. Once done, return via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

Comment: Okay, I did that. I am hesitant because a few prompts for my login came up and one was successful. I have installed several times and am concerned about different desktops being out there - an afterthought realization.

Comment: https://www.flickr.com/photos/142933146@N07/27727585714/in/dateposted-public/

Comment: Since this comment my computer was disconnected via the AC adapter. I am the account holder for amyhmilam@yahoo.com, luxluv777@yahoo.com, amymilam@gmail.com,  amyhmilam@gmail.com, and amyhmilam@yahoo.com. I have to regain access to a few, which should not be a problem.

Comment: PS - I installed it and have been using Ubuntu since 2011 - so I knew the guest session is part of Linux's design/safety which is pretty typical to most OS's but furthermore...

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/93951/login-to-account-reverts-to-login-screen-guest-login-ok

Comment: I am not well and will hopefully have this amount of control over my computer tues to work on this - after I see the doctor again

Answer (score 0):

The mounts have been hacked. [my google account, ls home directory, mount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fP0A4.png)

I have had to revert to /dev/sda1 numerous times in the past. I cannot compete at that level.