# How to reset Ubuntu to act as at the first start?

Tags: reset

I have an ASUS EEE PC 1011PX with Ubuntu Linux Desktop Edition v 10.10. I want to revert its state before its first start where a wizard came up and asked things username, passwords, etc... I hope there is a command or something to revert everything back to the first start.

Comment: that wizard is available when you install.  What is stopping you from reinstalling from CD/USB?

Comment: The only chanse would a fresh install? I do not have any install media. I have only USB for booting any install. Is there a special ubuntu for netbooks and for USB?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reset GNOME to the defaults?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults)

Answer (score 2):

The wizard you mentioned is only available from a fresh install - it is part of the installation routine.

If you want to reset your desktop then there is a [great answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults) describing this.

An alternative would be just to create a new user account and copy the files from one account to the other.

10.10 is almost out of support (April 2011) - so you perhaps should consider upgrading.

Obviously 12.04 will be available at that time - full instructions on how to install from USB is available from [ubuntu.com](http://ubuntu.com).

Unlike 10.10 - there is not a specific version of ubuntu for netbooks.  The netbook design has been combined into the one Unity interface (hence its name).  For netbooks, my recommendation would be to use the Unity-2D interface since it is much lighter for the lower cpu-powered netbook.

Answer (score 2):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>
2. `rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity`
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>
4. Restart

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to upgrade to 12.04, I run it on a first gen eee701 with no issues at all. Unetbootin can create a bootable 12.04 USB stick.