# Unity lenses are all empty

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

My dash is completely empty. The alt-f2 run screen load applications if I type in the commands. But the others are completely empty on my own profile. In a guest profile, they work as expected.

I've read the other similar questions and tried both of these options. Neither had any effect:

- `apt-get install --reinstall unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files unity-lens-music`
- `unity --reset`

I've upgraded from 10.14 to 12.04 and the lens / dash has never worked.

What could be left over in my home directory from a previous version that would mean these lenses are empty?

Comment: Hard to know which setting, but take a look at the first answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults and http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do

Comment: Turns out Krytarik pointed me to the solution here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11689567#post11689567 I had to delete my zeitgeist database. It's working now, very happy days. :-)

Comment: FYI 12.04 is still in development, you *shouldn't* have upgraded yet.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Questions about Ubuntu+1 (at time of writing 12.04) are off-topic, because its still rapidly changing and its entirely likely they might be a bug. I suggest that you look at the second link from bodhi for any future problems.