# Desktop icon position not remembered

Tags: icons

Every time I bootup my Ubuntu 11.10, the desktop icons are shuffled and placed on top of each other.  I wonder if this is a settings problem (e.g. I can remove some configure file in my home folder to solve this problem PERMANANTELY), or it is a bug I shall report?

Thanks,
Shannon

Answer (score 3):

If you right click on your open desktop somewhere and click on the "keep aligned" setting your icons should line back into place.I ve had that problem and that fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Follow the answer above or reset GNOME as described on this post

- [How do I reset GNOME to the defaults?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults)

There is a big chance this is just a glitch and a reset will make it work as it should.