# I broke my unity by using cairo dock PPA, how do I fix it?

Tags: unity, compiz, cairo-dock

I installed cairo dock like so

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cairo-dock-team
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cairo-dock cairo-dock-plug-ins
```

after i booted up and selected with graphics effect i couldn't see anything
 
pop up expect the desktop and mouse after a min or two i power off my machine
then booted up unity but couldn't see anything but the panel which was blue 
according to my theme. i purged the ppa and did some extra stuff like so

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:cairo-dock-team
sudo apt-get purge cairo-dock cairo-dock-plug-ins
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get check
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
nautilus --check
```

it removed everything no error whit the exception of nautilus --check

```
blade@blade-SATELLITE-L750:~$ nautilus --check
running nautilus_self_check_file_utilities
running nautilus_self_check_file_operations
running nautilus_self_check_directory
running nautilus_self_check_file
running nautilus_self_check_icon_container
running nautilus_self_check_file_utilities
running nautilus_self_check_file_operations
running nautilus_self_check_directory
running nautilus_self_check_file
running nautilus_self_check_icon_container
```

my question is how do i get unity up and running again

i already tried `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` if something got 
deleted with out me knowing it. and also `unity reset` which works. for the dash but after a reboot it wouldn't  start up again i also tried `sudo compiz --replace` but no luck
 here is the output for `compiz --replace`

```
Backend     : ini
Integration : true
Profile     : default
Adding plugins
Skipping upgrade com.canonical.unity.unity.01.upgrade
Skipping upgrade com.canonical.unity.unity.02.upgrade
Initializing core options...done
Initializing bailer options...[ERROR]: Option "fatal_fallback_mode" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "custom_fallback_window_manager" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "custom_alternative_shell" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "poor_performance_fallback" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "bad_performance_threshold" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "bad_plugins" already defined
done
Initializing detection options...[ERROR]: Option "detect_bad_pci" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "detect_bad_drivers" already defined
done
Initializing composite options...[ERROR]: Option "slow_animations_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "detect_refresh_rate" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "refresh_rate" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "unredirect_fullscreen_windows" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "force_independent_output_painting" already defined
done
Initializing opengl options...[ERROR]: Option "texture_filter" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "lighting" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "sync_to_vblank" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "texture_compression" already defined
done
Initializing decor options...[ERROR]: Option "shadow_radius" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "shadow_opacity" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "shadow_color" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "shadow_x_offset" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "shadow_y_offset" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "command" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "mipmap" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "decoration_match" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "shadow_match" already defined
done
Initializing mousepoll options...[ERROR]: Option "mouse_poll_interval" already defined
done
Initializing vpswitch options...done
Initializing animation options...[ERROR]: Option "open_effects" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "open_durations" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "open_matches" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "open_options" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "open_random_effects" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "close_effects" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "close_durations" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "close_matches" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "close_options" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "close_random_effects" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "minimize_effects" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "minimize_durations" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "minimize_matches" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "minimize_options" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "minimize_random_effects" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "shade_effects" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "shade_durations" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "shade_matches" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "shade_options" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "shade_random_effects" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "focus_effects" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "focus_durations" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "focus_matches" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "focus_options" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "all_random" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "time_step" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "curved_fold_amp_mult" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "curved_fold_zoom_to_taskbar" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "dodge_mode" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "dodge_gap_ratio" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "dream_zoom_to_taskbar" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "glide1_away_position" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "glide1_away_angle" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "glide1_zoom_to_taskbar" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "glide2_away_position" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "glide2_away_angle" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "glide2_zoom_to_taskbar" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "horizontal_folds_amp_mult" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "horizontal_folds_num_folds" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "horizontal_folds_zoom_to_taskbar" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "magic_lamp_moving_end" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "magic_lamp_grid_res" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "magic_lamp_open_start_width" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "magic_lamp_wavy_moving_end" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "magic_lamp_wavy_grid_res" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "magic_lamp_wavy_max_waves" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "magic_lamp_wavy_amp_min" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "magic_lamp_wavy_amp_max" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "magic_lamp_wavy_open_start_width" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "rollup_fixed_interior" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "sidekick_num_rotations" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "sidekick_springiness" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "sidekick_zoom_from_center" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "wave_width" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "wave_amp_mult" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "zoom_from_center" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "zoom_springiness" already defined
done
Initializing snap options...done
compiz (expo) - Warn: failed to bind image to texture
Initializing expo options...done
Initializing move options...[ERROR]: Option "initiate_button" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "initiate_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "opacity" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "constrain_y" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "snapoff_maximized" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "lazy_positioning" already defined
done
Initializing place options...[ERROR]: Option "workarounds" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "mode" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "multioutput_mode" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "force_placement_match" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "position_matches" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "position_x_values" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "position_y_values" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "position_constrain_workarea" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "mode_matches" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "mode_modes" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "viewport_matches" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "viewport_x_values" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "viewport_y_values" already defined
done
Initializing grid options...[ERROR]: Option "put_center_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "put_left_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "put_right_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "put_top_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "put_bottom_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "put_topleft_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "put_topright_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "put_bottomleft_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "put_bottomright_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "put_maximize_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "put_restore_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "top_left_corner_action" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "top_edge_action" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "top_right_corner_action" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "left_edge_action" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "right_edge_action" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "bottom_left_corner_action" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "bottom_edge_action" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "bottom_right_corner_action" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "snapoff_maximized" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "snapback_windows" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "left_edge_threshold" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "right_edge_threshold" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "top_edge_threshold" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "bottom_edge_threshold" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "draw_indicator" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "outline_color" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "fill_color" already defined
done
Initializing gnomecompat options...[ERROR]: Option "main_menu_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "run_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "command_screenshot" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "run_command_screenshot_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "command_window_screenshot" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "run_command_window_screenshot_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "command_terminal" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "run_command_terminal_key" already defined
done
Initializing wall options...[ERROR]: Option "show_switcher" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "miniscreen" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "preview_timeout" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "preview_scale" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "edge_radius" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "border_width" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "outline_color" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "background_gradient_base_color" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "background_gradient_highlight_color" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "background_gradient_shadow_color" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "thumb_gradient_base_color" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "thumb_gradient_highlight_color" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "thumb_highlight_gradient_base_color" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "thumb_highlight_gradient_shadow_color" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "arrow_base_color" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "arrow_shadow_color" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "allow_wraparound" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "slide_duration" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "no_slide_match" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "left_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "left_button" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "right_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "right_button" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "up_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "up_button" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "down_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "down_button" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "next_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "next_button" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "prev_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "prev_button" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "left_window_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "right_window_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "up_window_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "down_window_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "flip_left_edge" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "flip_right_edge" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "flip_up_edge" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "flip_down_edge" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "mmmode" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "edgeflip_pointer" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "edgeflip_move" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "edgeflip_dnd" already defined
done
Initializing ezoom options...[ERROR]: Option "set_zoom_area" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "ensure_visibility" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "zoom_in_button" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "zoom_in_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "zoom_out_button" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "zoom_out_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "zoom_box_button" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "center_mouse_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "zoom_specific_1_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "zoom_spec1" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "zoom_specific_2_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "zoom_spec2" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "zoom_specific_3_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "zoom_spec3" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "spec_target_focus" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "lock_zoom_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "pan_left_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "pan_right_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "pan_up_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "pan_down_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "fit_to_zoom_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "fit_to_window_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "zoom_factor" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "minimum_zoom" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "zoom_mode" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "scale_mouse" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "scale_mouse_dynamic" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "scale_mouse_static" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "hide_original_mouse" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "restrain_mouse" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "restrain_margin" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "pan_factor" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "follow_focus" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "focus_fit_window" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "autoscale_min" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "always_focus_fit_window" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "follow_focus_delay" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "speed" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "timestep" already defined
done
Initializing workarounds options...[ERROR]: Option "keep_minimized_windows" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "legacy_fullscreen" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "firefox_menu_fix" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "ooo_menu_fix" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "notification_daemon_fix" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "java_fix" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "java_taskbar_fix" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "qt_fix" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "convert_urgency" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "aiglx_fragment_fix" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "fglrx_xgl_fix" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "force_glx_sync" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "no_wait_for_video_sync" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "force_swap_buffers" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "sticky_alldesktops" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "alldesktop_sticky_match" already defined
done
Initializing staticswitcher options...done
Initializing resize options...[ERROR]: Option "initiate_button" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "initiate_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "mode" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "resize_from_center" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "border_color" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "fill_color" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "normal_match" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "outline_match" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "rectangle_match" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "stretch_match" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "resize_from_center_match" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "outline_modifier" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "rectangle_modifier" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "stretch_modifier" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "centered_modifier" already defined
done
Initializing fade options...[ERROR]: Option "fade_mode" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "fade_speed" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "fade_time" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "window_match" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "visual_bell" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "fullscreen_visual_bell" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "dim_unresponsive" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "unresponsive_brightness" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "unresponsive_saturation" already defined
done
Initializing scale options...done
Initializing session options...[ERROR]: Option "save_legacy" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "ignore_match" already defined
done
compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x1800004
```

Comment: I need my Ubuntu for school work, if i can't fixed this, i am forced to do a clean install of Ubuntu, I like to be able to fix this for other users, and to make the Ubuntu experience more enjoyable.

Comment: try resetting back to your defaults for compiz etc as per http://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults

Comment: thanks in the link the answer was for gnome2/gnome3 i got scared so i didn't run that, BUT it gave me an idea (Which i came acros in the past)that idea was this command 'sudo gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1' and this 'sudo gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/compizconfig-1' i rebooted and it worked perfectly. jeej :)

Comment: well done - create an answer and please accept it by clicking the tick button to close the question.

Comment: alright i'l do that

Comment: it said i can accept this answer tomorrow... guess I'll do that then, Thanks for the help, couldn't have done it without you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got unity working again by running these commands in the gnome-terminal and rebooting

Alternatively - <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to move to TTY1, login and perform the following:

**quick-note**: all your compiz settings will be reset!

```
sudo gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1
sudo gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/compizconfig-1
```

Answer (score 2):

If Panel and unity both disappeared you can get it back by typing below command in terminal

```
unity --reset
```

I guess this will help you.