# How to reset Unity after being replaced by Cairo-Dock?

Tags: unity, 12.04, cairo-dock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I broke my unity by using cairo dock PPA, how do I fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123059/i-broke-my-unity-by-using-cairo-dock-ppa-how-do-i-fix-it)

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04. I had installed Cairo-Dock as well. My brother closed something in Cairo-Dock, He doesn't know what exactly he did as he is new to Ubuntu.
After he did that, The Unity panel is completely missing. Even the launcher is missing. The Cairo-Dock panel is also missing.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Okay.
It seems like your brother disabled or played around with the unity plug-in.

If you have CompizConfigurationManager installed,open it.

Or else install it from the Software Center.

After you have it,

1. Open it and go to "Ubuntu Unity Plugin" under the "desktop" menu

2.In the Settings click on the Enable Unity Plugin option.!

[image: Step-1]

[image: Step-2]

Answer (score 0):

My guess is whatever happened disabled Unity (it is just a plugin for Compiz). Install the Compiz Config Settings Manager (ccsm):

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Then run the manager:

```
ccsm
```

Look for the Unity plugin and enable it.