# How to resize fonts?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, fonts

After upgrading to 12.04 my fonts are now huge. The only way I have found to solve it, is by running the following command after startup:

```
$ sudo gnome-settings-daemon 

** (process:3299): WARNING **: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

** (gnome-settings-daemon:3285): WARNING **: Unable to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

** (gnome-settings-daemon:3285): WARNING **: Failed to get session for pid: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.GeneralError: Unable to lookup session information for process '3285'

** (gnome-settings-daemon:3285): WARNING **: Failed to get session for pid: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.GeneralError: Unable to lookup session information for process '3285'

(gnome-settings-daemon:3285): color-plugin-WARNING **: failed to get edid: unable to get EDID for output
[1335525273,000,xklavier.c:xkl_engine_start_listen/]    The backend does not require manual layout management - but it is provided by the application

(gnome-settings-daemon:3285): libappindicator-CRITICAL **: app_indicator_set_label: assertion `IS_APP_INDICATOR (self)' failed

(gnome-settings-daemon:3285): color-plugin-WARNING **: unable to get EDID for xrandr-default: unable to get EDID for output

(gnome-settings-daemon:3285): color-plugin-WARNING **: failed to reset xrandr-default gamma tables: gamma size is zero
```

Can somebody help solve this problem?

**Update 2**: I have the same problem in unity

**Update 1**: Attached screenshot:

[image]

**Update 3**
To follow up, I never found a solution and ended up reinstalling it all

Comment: What else have you tried, and what other desktop environments, if any, do you have installed?

Comment: I haven't tried much else, but as the title says gnome 3 is installed, and was installed before the upgrade as well. I have attached a screenshot showing the problem.

Comment: If you reset your gnome configuration, does this fix this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults

Comment: It did not help removing the folders suggested in your link. But when I create a new user everything looks fine and logs in with this, everything looks fine.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work: try to delete the *.fontconfig* file on your home folder.

Comment: It did not help to remove .fontconfig

Answer (score 2):

Try to install gnome-tweak-tool via terminal:

> `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`

Then start it with

> `gnome-tweak-tool`

on terminal and go to font settings.
Set the fonts to "Ubuntu" with font size "11" and for window titles "Ubuntu Bold".

By the way: What you describe should be a bug, but with this workaround you can get your fonts set to default.

Comment: The font is already set to ubuntu and font is 11, changing it does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: Have you tried to see what happens, if you create a new user and login with them?

Comment: When I login with a new user everything seems fine