# Why does installing gnome shell extensions from extensions.gnome.org fail silently?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

On a fresh Ubuntu install (12.04, 64-bit), after installing gnome-shell, I've tried to install some extensions from extensions.gnome.org but got no result. I've tried with Firefox and Chromium and got the same issue.

1. Open any extension page on extensions.gnome.org.
2. Switch extension to "ON". Agree with confirmation about installation.
3. Nothing happens and nothing has been installed (`.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` is empty).

I've checked .xsession-errors, Firefox's javascript console, gnome-shell console errors (Alt-F2 + looking glass). There isn't any trace of any error.

Comment: Try to remove/rename to extensions backup ".local/share/gnome-shell/extensions" (you may need to do it as root if it is a permission problem), and let gnome add them back when you install extensions. This might not work and might not be the true solution but it is one of the easiest things you can do.(Why this is in the comments.)

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem myself and I tried resetting GNOME settings and it worked for me. After resetting GNOME settings, try logging out and back in (and to be safe, try rebooting as well) and now, you should hopefully be able to install the GNOME extensions.

- [How do I reset GNOME to the defaults?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults)

Comment: still no luck :(

Comment: I do not use it. Firefox/Chromium both have plugin enabled. I can press button off, it turn to on, but nothing happends. On next launch it is still off. I thought that was some issues with access to extensions folder, but the Bunnys answer did not work also.

Comment: YEY :) it works, I had to reboot after GNOME reset, logout did not help. Still have issues in chromium, but installation works in firefox

Comment: @Pascal if this answer help you, please click on accept button. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You must have **unzip** in order to install extensions from the website.

```
sudo apt-get install unzip
```

Comment: This solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same problem, but this started only a few days ago.

Also running the 64 bit install.
Gnome-shell was installed using ricotz and gnome3-team ppa.
Choice of browser (even epiphany-browser) makes no difference.

Maybe this helps in closing in on the error?

What does work is to go to the extension homepages, download them, and put them in the .local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ folder manually.

Comment: I am too lazy, to do manually :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04-amd64.

The only thing that worked for me was starting Firefox with a blank profile.
Close all Firefox windows and open a terminal or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `firefox -P`.

This will start the Profile Manager here you can choose a profile and create a new blank one that you can use for Gnome extensions. Use the same command to return to your old profile.

I believe it's an issue with Firefox... but just can't get around it. In Firefox I've cleared all history, disabled all extensions, in gnome-shell, reset and reinstall but to no avail.

Comment: I don't believe it's related to Firefox, I've tried with Epiphany and got the same result, nothing.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I had noticed permissions errors in `.xsession-errors` when trying to add any simple extension. In this case: "Remove Accessibility":

```
checkdir:  cannot create extraction directory: /home/nate/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/removeaccesibility@lomegor Permission denied
```

Ran `ls -la`:

```
drwx------  3 root root  4096 Jul 15 16:38 gnome-shell
```

Both root user and group owned the directory. Changing the owner resolved my problems:

```
sudo chown -R nate:nate /home/nate/.local/gnome-shell
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too. What I have read from other some what related threads is that installing extensions from the web page may stop working after an upgrade.

I noticed that my existing extensions were stored in `/usr/local/gnome-shell/extenssions` and not in the `.local/gnome-shell/extenssions` folder. Further on, only `root` had write permissions to the `/usr/local/gnome-shell/extenssions` folder. As a test I did a `chmod 777` on this folder, ie. full rights to everything and everyone, and now I can install extensions from the web page.

This is not a good approach, but maybe it can help someone to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

had similar problem on my 14.04 + gnome 3 setup

fixed by just creating `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/` folder

Answer (score -2):

Try the browsers Firefox and Epiphany. Don't close the tab immediately after accepting the extension installation, especially when you have a slow internet connection.

Comment: I've tried with Chromium and FF with the same negative result. Copying extensions from my home computer to ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions did the job. But this is just a workaround. Perhaps, extensions.gnome.org fails because my professional computer is connected via a proxy ?

Comment: That could be. Is it possible for you to get a connection without proxy temporarily to test that?

Comment: No. But before 12.04 installation, with previous Ubuntu version, I could get extensions to install normally even through this same proxy.

Comment: Please open up a terminal, type `gnome-shell --replace`. This will restart your gnome-shell. Then try again to install any extension and look for errors in the terminal output. If you find some, please post them here.

Comment: Thanks for this advice. Running gnome-shell --replace issues with the following errors (see next comments). Then, installing extensions still fails silently (no more errors in console).

Comment: First error (on running gome-shell --replace) :
gnome-shell --replace
Window Manager warning : Log level 8: shell_tray_manager_manage_stage: assertion `manager->priv->stage == NULL' failed
      JS LOG: GNOME Shell started at Fri Jun 01 2012 12:57:11 GMT+0200 (CEST)
      JS LOG: AppTrackerError: get_window_app returned null and there was no record of metaWindow in internal database

Comment: Next error (on running gnome-shell --replace):
Window Manager warning : Log level 16: STACK_OP_REMOVE: window 0x65 not in stack

(gnome-shell:6882): folks-WARNING **: Failed to find primary PersonaStore with type ID 'eds' and ID 'system'.
Individuals will not be linked properly and creating new links between Personas will not work.
The configured primary PersonaStore's backend may not be installed. If you are unsure, check with your distribution.

Comment: If there is no additional output, you can't find the problem this way. I have no more ideas, sorry.