# Cannot install gnome extensions from GNOME site

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does installing gnome shell extensions from extensions.gnome.org fail silently?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142054/why-does-installing-gnome-shell-extensions-from-extensions-gnome-org-fail-silent)

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 and installed gnome-shell on my system. I am attempting to download the user theme extensions from extensions.gnome.org, but I can't see this "switch" everyone's talking about. I've tried both Chromium and Firefox browsers on the site. I found a similar subject on

- [How to install GNOME Shell extensions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-to-install-gnome-shell-extensions)

I followed the directions but I have a warning about GNOME common dependencies. I installed GNOME-extensions-common without an error but I still cannot install user-themes, and I can't find the mysterious "switch". Any ideas?

EDIT: My GNOME version is 3.4.1.

---

I've tried resetting my GNOME settings. Using the directions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults/56314#56314). I still get no switch on the extension site, and here is the error I get from the terminal:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme : Depends : gnome-shell-extensions-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Please, do mention your Gnome 3 version. This might resume to not having the required version.

Comment: @Andrew did you try resetting the GNOME settings?

Comment: @jokerdino how do I do that..?

Comment: Try this answer given under GNOME3: http://askubuntu.com/a/56314/25798

Comment: @AndrewJamesAdams After resetting the settings, did you not reboot?

Comment: @jokerdino completely shutdown and restarted.

Comment: Try installing Epiphany browser and see if you can browse the web using that. If you can't, we can figure out the problem.

Comment: @jokerdino I've installed Epiphany and the switch still does not appear. Is it possible that it is a beta bug w/ gnome site?

Comment: @AndrewJamesAdams that is possible as well. I'll try and see if there are other ways of solving the problem. Good luck otherwise.