# How to completely remove and reinstall Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, delete

I want to reinstall Ubuntu, but I also want all information and settings to disappear. So everything looks like the first time I installed it. Is it possible to do so via Terminal? Or what are the steps I should follow?

Comment: reklated: http://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults and http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration

Answer (score 12):

You cannot perform a reinstallation of Ubuntu from an existing installation.

1. Use Ubuntu live disk to boot up.
2. Select *Install Ubuntu on hard disk*.
3. Keep on following the wizard.
4. Select the *Erase Ubuntu and reinstall* option.

   [image]

Comment: Does this set-up still work in 12.04 and do you need to have your home directory on a separate partition?  Does this improve things?

Comment: Yea, it works (I never needed to reinstall though so not tested by me),  I never had `/home` in separate partion. Separate `/home` partition to separate your data. And improvement in what context (what improves what)?