# Safely remove linux partition and grub from windows

Tags: grub2, removing

How do I safely remove ubuntu partition from windows?

I messed up with ubuntu update; now the desktop is empty, no launchbar and no sidebar, although all the files are there and the terminal is working.

I'd like to delete the linux partion and start a new ubuntu.

Comment: Why not just reinstall on the existing Ubuntu partition? Also, [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/17381/12864) might be something to try first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to completely remove and reinstall Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223301/how-to-completely-remove-and-reinstall-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

#### you may try to reinstall the unity it will 
            bring back the launchbar and sidebar.

```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
  sudo apt-get install unity
```

Comment: will 
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
not delete my documents?

Answer (score 1):

If You want to reinstall Ubuntu,You don't need to delete Ubuntu partition From Windows. You can delete partition while reinstalling Ubuntu. When Ubuntu is going to install ,It will detect your old installation and ask for Replace. You can also choose **Something Else** , Find and delete / partition.