# Booting From Usb From Ubuntu

Tags: boot

I currently have the latest version of Ubuntu installed. I was wondering how do I boot from a USB with Ubunutu on it. This is with the intention of re-loading ubuntu onto my computer.

At the moment I have only Ubuntu on my computer. When I was running windows on an old computer you would press f12 or something to access the BIOS, however on this computer, running windows 8, there is no pause to press f12 and I had to go into settings and choose to re-boot and access the BIOS as described here: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-access-the-bios-on-a-windows-8-computer/

Thanks for any help.

Comment: BIOS settings is not related to windows settings. and Do you want to install Ubuntu? please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/526688/edit) your question and add more details exactly what do you want. thanks

Comment: What are you booting on?

Comment: @KasiyA I have edited my question does it make more sense now?

Comment: Still I don't know what you want. What is your question exactly here? Do you want to boot from LIVE USB/CD with trying Ubuntu without installation? or you want to boot from USB to start new installation of Ubuntu?

Comment: @KasiyA Sorry, I want to boot from the USB to start a new installation. I want to do this http://askubuntu.com/questions/223301/how-to-completely-remove-and-reinstall-ubuntu but with a USB not CD (as I have no cd drive)

Comment: And so your system doesn't boot from USB? right?

Comment: @KasiyA Right, I have ubunut installed as my only operating system and if I turn off my computer, insert the USB and turn on it will just boot straight to the ubuntu that is installed on my computer without noticing the memory stick

Comment: Can you access your BIOS, by pressing <Esc> key or <Delete> or F12 or some thing F11 or F9 or F2?

Comment: @KasiyA Yes I got it to work now, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to boot an OS (Ubuntu) from USB. In this scenario all the data is loaded into your system memory and whenever you restart the computer all your local data will be lost! But there is a workaround, if you create a **Persistent Live USB**. The persistence allows you to keep your preferences and data even after reboot so you can install applications and save your data on the live system, it will be saved on the USB.

A Persistent Live USB should be 4GB or bigger, the OS will take up 1-2GB of space and the rest will be used as persistent storage on your USB.

There is a very nice and easy GUI application for windows that i suggest you to use in order to create a Live Persistent USB. The application called [YUMI – Multiboot USB Creator](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/).

Comment: What I want to do is re-load ubuntu and wipe all the stuff on my current computer. I downloaded a bad version of wine and I can't find where all the things that I installed using it are and so I thought it would be easier to start over and this was the only way that i knew how to

Comment: You should be able to do `sudo apt-get purge <package-name>`.