# Reinstall Ubuntu in an Ubuntu laptop

Tags: 18.04

I had installed Ubuntu 18.04  from a usb drive in an hp/amd Windows machine  and I erased windows. installation completed but soon discovered that my network adapter was not found by the OS. how should I troubleshoot...and would like to do this installation again..

Comment: You can reinstall from the same USB that you used to install the OS in the first place.  To troubleshoot the wireless card, please execute the command `lspci -knn | grep 0280` and append the results of that command to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My WiFi adapter is not working at all, how to troubleshoot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235279/my-wifi-adapter-is-not-working-at-all-how-to-troubleshoot) and [How to completely remove and reinstall Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223301/)