# re-install Ubuntu software of same version

Tags: upgrade

I updated from v16 of ubuntu to v8.  When I did that all went well.

A lot of things were funky (e.g., there is no pip and it won't let me add one).  The best advice so far is to re-install v18 again.

'Software Updater" app runs, but ends up saying "the software on this computer is up-to-date".

How do I get it to reinstall the latest version of Ubuntu over the (somewhat messed up) current OS?

Addendum:

Someone asked for a screenshot.  Here is one from another user who had the exact same problem, but none of the suggested fixes fixed it for me:
[image: no pip message]

BTW, the updater does give me a settings button and pages, but none of them are about the install I want to do.  They control, for example, what the upgrade and patch methodology (daily, automatic, etc.) do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to completely remove and reinstall Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/223301/)

Comment: v16 to v8??  What does that mean.  Ubuntu desktop and server releases use the year.month format, so 20.04 means the 2020-April release of Ubuntu. Ubuntu IoT and appliance releases (based on *snaps*) use year only, such as Ubuntu Core 16 - but there is no "v".  Also if that's the year, any releases from 2008 are now very far *end-of-life* and should be treated as insecure if you're on the web. Please clarify!?   You mention v18 later, so is this an IoT appliance? running the *snap* based release of Ubuntu Core?

Comment: Call me naive, but when I look for an OS image to download the choices are 20.4.1, 18.4, and 16.4.  Perhaps there is some secret encoding scheme, but these sure look like versions 16, 18,and 20.  This is an ordinary laptop.

Comment: There are many tens of ISOs you can download, and *snap* based ones for devices and appliances do have a *year* format as they only have a single release in a year. Desktop and Server releases use the *year.month* format as multiple releases per year; no 20.4.1 but it was 20.04.1 (the updated 2020-April release ISO, or 20.04), 18.04(and number, be it 18.04, 18.04.1, .. 18.04.5.   You can install appliance releases on a laptop, but you'll get no GUI as devices are usually headless (no display) with limited memory having a single function (eg. installation to a fridge, router, microwave..)