# Ubuntu fails to load Gnome 3 session

Tags: gnome

I have Ubuntu 12.10 installed with the Gnome shell which used to work fine. I have two accounts, my own with administrator privileges and my daughter's with standard privileges.

I had trouble loading a font in font manager. The system was froze and I used <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and afterwards <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> which caused a rebbot.

Now, my daughter's account works well and loads normally in with both Unity and Gnome 3.
My own account fails to load both Gnome 3 and Unity. I was able to open a new account with admin privileges and used with no issues in Gnome 3.

Is there a way I can repair my own account?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please provide more information about what exact error you get/what exactly happens if you try to login with your account.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that your configuration is broken somehow. You should try deleting all your settings for gnome3 and/or Unity. There is a very good explanation of this in the answer to this question:

[How do I reset GNOME to the defaults?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults)