# Search results in GNOME Shell 3.8

Tags: gnome, search

I have two users on my Ubuntu 13.04. Both use GNOME Shell 3.8 from the PPA. The problem I have is that with one of my user, the search tool in GNOME Shell does not work well. For example, searching for "libre" won't return me any of the LibreOffice software suite. With the other user, it works well.

I tried to reinstall LibreOffice, no changes. I also tried to reset GNOME Shell according to [How do I reset GNOME to the defaults?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults) also resulting in no changes.

Any idea?