# Display settings fail to apply on 13.04 with Gnome 3.6/3.8

Tags: gnome

When running the Display settings (`gnome-control-center display`) under Gnome 3.6 on Ubuntu 13.04 I'm unable to apply any settings (even if nothing changes). The error I get is:

`Failed to apply configuration: %s
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon was not provided by any .service files.`

Background:

I've tried to use the newer 3.8 release from the PPA's but that didn't help, I've now reverted to the 3.6 release. I've also tried removing all my gnome related config files, but that didn't make a difference.

The error message:
[image: Screenshot of error message]

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by removing every config file (`~/.*`) from my home directory. Previously I had attempted to remove all gnome related files but this didn't help.

(I followed: [How do I reset GNOME to the defaults?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults))

I still don't know what old config file caused this, but I recommend moving all your config files to a backup directory and moving them back one by one. If you want to test if this will help, login as a guest and see if you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've up-voted this answer mistakenly (as I meant down-voting it instead if I had enough karma juice) by not being pretty sure about the quite radical consequence of removing all hidden files from one personal home directory.  @peter have you find other alternatives in between?

Comment: `rm ~/.* ` is not a good idea, there are alot of import files in there that could break you whole login session. 
My advice is to create a new user, copy the docs / and other folder into this new user directory and then remove the old broken user when you no longer need it.