# How can I mirror two monitors with 14.04 on a Dell 5570?

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, xrandr

I've just upgraded to a Dell E5570 and am running 14.04LTS.    I want to be able to attach an external monitor, but in Mirror mode.  (I'm running fvwm with multiple virtual windows and I need to be able to see all of them on the external monitor.)   When I attach the external monitor, everything works, but only in extended or "twinview" mode.      From gnome-control-center display, when I switch to mirror mode, and click Apply,  I get the same error that has been reported elsewhere, in particular [here](http://%20particular%20%20i.e.,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown:%20The%20name%20org.gnome.SettingsDaemon%20was%20not%20provided%20by%20any%20.service%20files) and also [here, with a screenshot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301373/display-settings-fail-to-apply-on-13-04-with-gnome-3-6-3-8) i.e.,

```
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon was not provided by any .service files
```

My problem seems different from those previously reported, since I have no problems with extended mode.   The threads above suggest that xrandr or arandr can fix these kinds of problems.   But I've searched the documentation for xrandr and arandr, neither seem to have an option for mirror mode.

On a previous laptop (Dell E6530, running 12.04), I was able to fix this problem by installing an nvidia driver.    Have attempted to do this on the new E5570, but have been unable to get it to work.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Here's the output from xrandr

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   59.9     48.0
   1680x1050      60.0     59.9
   1600x1024      60.2
   1400x1050      60.0
   1600x900       60.0
   1280x1024      60.0
   1440x900       59.9
   1280x960       60.0
   1368x768       60.0
   1360x768       59.8     60.0
   1152x864       60.0
   1280x720       60.0
   1024x768       60.0
   1024x576       60.0
   960x540        60.0
   800x600        60.3     56.2
   864x486        60.0
   640x480        59.9
   720x405        60.0
   640x360        60.0
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP3 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 930mm x 523mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   59.9
   1680x1050      60.0
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0
   1280x960       75.0
   1152x864       75.0     60.0
   1024x768       75.1     75.0     60.0
   832x624        74.6
   800x600        75.0     60.3
   640x480        75.0     60.0
   720x400        70.1
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I have a single external monitor, but am running fvwm, which is a desktop manager that enables me to have multiple *virtual* desktops.   The image below is a schematic map of what my setup looks like, i.e., there a six virtual desktops, in a 2x3 configuration, each one has multiple xterms open.

[image: Here's a picture of my virtual screen setup]

Jacob, your xrandr suggestion enabled me to view the left-most and the right-most columns, but not the middle column of these virtual desktops.   Currently, I still have a 2x3 setup with the left column, the right column, and a blank column.   As I mentioned last time, it's striking that the middle column of virtual desktops (each screen in the middle has two xterms, including the one that's in focus in the image) is the column that's not visible now. But when I attached the external monitor originally, and was in extended mode, the middle column was the only column that I could see.

I'd very much like to be able to have access to all six virtual desktops, when I'm attached to an external monitor.   I hope this is clear!

Comment: could you post the output of the command `xrandr`?

Comment: Thanks @JacobVlijm, I've posted it at the bottom of my original question.

Comment: Hi Leo, did you notice the answer?

Comment: Sorry @JacobVlijm, I didn't get an email notification of your response.   Looks very promising, will work on it, and let you know.

Comment: you'll know in a second if you run the command in terminal :)

Comment: Thanks so much!   It works well, but not perfectly.       In brief, the problem is that I see two of the three  columns of screens that I have on my laptop (i.e., I have a 2 x3 screen setup) but not all three.   The column that's missing is the one that shows up in extended mode.     Will send a screenshot and more details if this doesn't help enough.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Your output shows two screens connected. There is a third? You should have mentioned, it is not in the moment you made the  xrandr output.

Comment: Leo, could you please clarify? I'd like to wrap it up.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I've added a detailed explanation to my main posting above.

Comment: See my edit. FVWM apparantly still assumes the screens are *next* to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your screen names (`eDP1, DP3`), the `xrandr` command:

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --pos 0x0 && xrandr --output DP3 --pos 0x0
```

should allign both screens on position `(x)0, (y)0` of the spanning screen layout, setting your screens mirrored in an alternative way.

Effectively, this would be exactly the same as mirroring your screens.

#### Put the command under a shortcut

To use the command in a convenient way, you can create a shortcut key with the command:

```
/bin/bash -c "xrandr --output eDP1 --pos 0x0 && xrandr --output DP3 --pos 0x0"
```

Choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

```
/bin/bash -c "xrandr --output eDP1 --pos 0x0 && xrandr --output DP3 --pos 0x0"
```

to a key shortcut of your choice.

#### Explanation

The two screens combined make a rectangle,

[image]

in which you can position the screens with the `xrandr`command:

```
xrandr --output <screen_name> --pos 0x0
```

where `0x0` are the `x/y` coordinates of the screen in the whole picture. By setting it to `0x0` for both screens, the screens coincide, effectively the same as being mirrored.

---

### EDIT

from your edit, I read you are using `FVWM` window manager, which apparantly (still) assumes the second screen is *next* to the first one. In that case

```
xrandr --output  eDP1 --auto --output DP3 --auto --same-as eDP1
```

should mirror the screens, but you'll have to see how `FVWM` reacts on this one.

Comment: Fraid that command just did exactly the same thing.   I guess it's a problem with  fvwm.   I'll try posting on that forum, but am not optimistic they'll be able to fix it...     Thanks very much for your patience and perserverance with this!   2/3 of the way is *a lot* better than nothing.

Comment: @LeoSimon did you straighten this out yet?  There's a follow-up on your fvwm forums topic...

Comment: Indeed, the problem is now solved, thanks to help from @nix_newb, details on http://fvwmforums.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=3138&p=14838#p14838