# Launch Icons: how do I get rid of them?

Tags: launcher

After browsing a commercial site www.kohls.com I suddenly got some "launch icons" in my bottom bar towards the right side.  They automatically go to pages on Kohl's website. I cannot get rid of them - tried everything, including even uninstalling and reinstalling Firefox. This has never happened on other websites.  Could Kohl's website be installing malware?  In any case, how do I get rid of them, short of a complete Ubuntu reinstall?  I am using Ubuntu 12.04, correctly updated, but with Gnome GUI instead of "unity" which I do not like at all.

Screenshot at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyltJ.png

Comment: Can you take a screen-shot <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> and post it on [Imgur](http://imgur.com/) and add a link to it in your question please?

Comment: I don't know how to do any of this.  Sorry, I am a lay end user.

Comment: Let me break it down for you then. Press the Print Screen key on your keyboard. This will take a screen-shot of your desktop. Save the file. Then go to Imgur using the link in my last comment, and upload it by clicking the "Computer" button in the upper right hand corner of the page. After you upload the screen shot, copy the url that Imgur makes for you. Then edit your question and paste the url and save the edit.

Comment: Thanks, Dash_plus_Java, but explain why this is important.

Comment: Thank you for adding the screen shot Cosy. It's important because it helps me and others see the icons that you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

These are shortcuts on the gnome panel and should be able to be removed.

Right click the bottom panel and select edit panel. Remove the shortcuts from the panel and save/exit.

Not sure why Kohls website would add these. That's a mystery to me.

Comment: Tried that quite a while ago.  Does not work - in fact, I get no response when right-clicking on the bottom panel.

Comment: Can you try reseting the gnome desktop? See the directions in the answer of this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults

Comment: Good point - this will remove pretty much ALL of the configuration though...

Comment: just tried this - did nothing as I suspected.  All 8 Kohl website icons are still there on the bottom bar, right side as in the screen shot.  This may be Xmas-sales malware (to keep me focused on Kohl), but if no one has anything but other speculative guesses as to how to fix it, I will just ignore these tenacious icons - since if I don't click on them, most likely only a little load on the machine.  This nuisance has taken more time than it is worth. It just isn't very aesthetic or satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the launcher and 'Remove from Panel'

You may need to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> or [image] first.

Comment: When I right click on the launcher icon, the only choices are "launch" and "properties".  Pressing the alt key first or holding it while clicking does not work.  Believe me, I have tried all the combinations I can think of.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled Firefox, I have removed the ubufox hamburger helper.  I have never installed the Firefox launch plug-in, I checked and it is indeed not installed now.  Just noting all this to avoid unnecessary suggestions.  The Kohl launchers point to pages that I did explore on their website - that is why I am suspicious of malware from Kohl.