# Logitech K260 wireless Keyboard -not working but mouse works after upgrade 13.04 to 13.10

Tags: 13.10, upgrade, mouse, logitech, wireless-keyboards

This is strange, but bear with me.
I upgraded my 13.04 to 13.10 and everything appeared to upgrade flawlessly.
At the end, I rebooted and was able to use Logitech K260 keyboard to type in my password and get to the desktop screen.  From that point on, 13.10 would not get any input from the keyboard, however the mouse works well.
Before I upgraded to 13.10, I, a few months ago, did a fresh install of 13.10 on a different partition.  I am using that installation of 13.10 to write this.
So, something is wrong with the upgrade as there are two bootable partitions, one working, and one not.
I would appreciate any help with this.
Thanks,
Bill

This is `dmesg | tail` for the working 13.10.  If you can point where to look for the not-working 13.10 I would appreciate it.

```
 dmesg | tail
[  674.392429] usb 5-2: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  685.499737] usb 5-2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ohci-pci
[  685.673020] usb 5-2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52e
[  685.673033] usb 5-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  685.673041] usb 5-2: Product: USB Receiver
[  685.673046] usb 5-2: Manufacturer: Logitech
[  685.681672] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.0/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.0/input/input13
[  685.681932] hid-generic 0003:046D:C52E.0003: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:13.0-2/input0
[  685.687249] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.0/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.1/input/input14
[  685.687702] hid-generic 0003:046D:C52E.0004: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:13.0-2/input1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said it works at the login, but then not any more. Did you try to login as guest user?

I am assuming something is wrong with your configuration. If this is the case, guest login should work just fine, and you should remove your settings files. See this answer:
[How do I reset GNOME to the defaults?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults)

Comment: Thank you for your insights.  I tried all of those listed but could not get the keyboard to work, so I used the 13.10 dvd that I burned to install the working system.  Since I had a backup of all my files, I did a fresh install and restored everything.  So far it works.  Too bad that the upgrade breaks it all.