# Reinstall launcher/taskbar

Tags: gnome-panel

A website put a launching icon in my taskbar/launcher, so I right clicked on it and a drop down menu came up that included an option to **delete bar** or something like that, and I clicked it, and now I have no launcher.

I have no buttons to shut the system down, I have no buttons for application menus and so on, so I can't get to any programs

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 with GNOME

How can I get the launcher back?

Comment: press ctrl + alt + t to open a terminal. if that doesn't work, press ctrl + alt + F2 and login with your username and password. from there you can type `sudo reboot` to reboot or `sudo poweroff` to poweroff. please be specific, what website?

Comment: Before I had like a bar acroos the top of the screen Left was a drop down menu with everything on it, right hand side was the time and power and system menu's that is what I have deleted . If I logout and come back as Guest I have it all back again

Comment: see here http://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults

Answer (score 1):

What I had to do was

- add a new panel by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd> and right click on a panel, and select **new panel**.
- Add **Main Menu** and **indicator applet Appmenu**.
- Move panel to the top of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

you can run this command to delete all your current settings to bring gnome back to default

```
rm -R .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity
```

if it complains that blah blah blah cannot be found, leave that one out of the command.

To explain, your user settings are found in .gnome and .gconf etc. to delete something, use the rm command. Use rm -R to delete a directory and contents as well.

Log out and log back in.

P.S. 13.10 hit EOL last year, you should consider upgrading to a newer version of ubuntu although I understand if you like 13.10 it's pretty solid.

Comment: that did not work thanks anyway. It is the applet panel I'm talking about just to try to clear things up