# Changing workspace shortcuts do not work

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, workspaces

Ubuntu 14.04. The shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> to change workspace and move applications do not work.

Here is the image of the shortcuts configuration
[image]

and here is the output of xev when pressing the combination

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
    root 0x25b, subw 0x0, time 5232252, (-456,71), root:(331,123),
    state 0x10, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
    root 0x25b, subw 0x0, time 5232883, (-456,71), root:(331,123),
    state 0x14, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
    root 0x25b, subw 0x0, time 5233443, (-456,71), root:(331,123),
    state 0x1c, keycode 114 (keysym 0xff53, Right), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
    root 0x25b, subw 0x0, time 5233548, (-456,71), root:(331,123),
    state 0x1c, keycode 114 (keysym 0xff53, Right), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
    root 0x25b, subw 0x0, time 5233900, (-456,71), root:(331,123),
    state 0x1c, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
    root 0x25b, subw 0x0, time 5233916, (-456,71), root:(331,123),
    state 0x14, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

ClientMessage event, serial 37, synthetic YES, window 0x4600001,
    message_type 0x12f (WM_PROTOCOLS), format 32, message 0x12d (WM_DELETE_WINDOW)
```

Other Ctrl+Alt shortcuts (like T to open the terminal and H to open the home) work fine.
I already tried to re-set them with no luck.

Any hint on how to solve the problem and being able to use them?

Comment: I am now suer that the problem is user-wide (the Guest session is not affected), but still it does not help me. So far I canceled a couple of times the configurations files and folder in my home, removed and reset the shourtcuts, removed and reset the workspaces. I do not know what to do more :(

Comment: Those shortcut are handled by Compiz. Try installing `ccsm`, then check if "Desktop Wall" enabled and check its binding is set. (Be Aware that ccsm is an advanced tool)

Answer (score 3):

For the shortcuts to work you need at the minimum the workspaces setting enabled:

> Settings - appearance - behaviour tab and tick the workspaces checkbox

Assuming that this is correct, the next step is to confirm if this is account specific or system wide.  Login to another account to confirm.

If you dont have access to another account, then look at account specific stuff.

You could try resetting Unity as per our [canonical Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/a/202020/29595):

If this still doesn't work, then you can use the ultimate "correct everything" method of clearing down all [Gnome settings](https://askubuntu.com/a/56314/29595):

Comment: The master at work!  ;-)

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately the problem has come again, but on a different computer now.

I did again as above (reset Unity, GTK2 and GTK3) but this time it did not solved the problem :( Any other hint?