# How to reset Ubuntu 14.04 completely

Tags: 14.04, configuration, default, reset

I'm using **Ubuntu 14.04** (dual boot - along with Windows 7) and I'm new to it. I needed to install **Apache, MySQL and PHP** as a part of my work. I installed each of those 3 packages separately using the tutorials given here and other sites.

Yesterday, I needed to remove and re-install the apache2 package due to "internal server error - 500". The installation was smooth but there were some errors since then. So, I decided to completely remove Apache, MySql and PHP. I removed it and re-installed again. But, the errors like "javascript-common" is still there. And I'm confused and not satisfied with the current status of my system.

I think, I need to **start over**. Do I need to completely remove Ubuntu and re-install it again? Or is there any way to reset the whole settings (and remove all the packages installed by me - i.e., reset to the phase when I installed Ubuntu)?

I saw [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults) question but I'm not sure whether resetting the GNOME to the defaults would solve my issue, since I'm new to Ubuntu or any other Linux distributions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you are starting the computer , choose the Ubuntu Recovery mode instead of the usual "Ubuntu" you used to choose.
Then choose Repair broken packages and follow it until the end