# Why does GNOME Shell Extensions installation from website not work?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I'm trying to install some GNOME Shell Extensions on Ubuntu 16.04 (64bit) from the web site extensions.gnome.org. I'm using Gnome 3.18 with LightDM.

I verified that Firefox has the Gnome Shell Integration plugin enabled, and the extension page loads with the on/off slider correctly displayed.

When I switch the slider to "on", I accept the dialog about installation but then nothing happens. After reloading the page, the slider is still "off".
Thus the extension is actually NOT installed and the directory .local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ remains unchanged.

I read older discussions whereas someone were suggesting to reset GNOME settings to default, as discussed here: [How do I reset GNOME to the defaults?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults), but that did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the `chrome-gnome-shell` package?

From the website:

> This extension provides integration with GNOME Shell and the corresponding extensions repository https://extensions.gnome.org You MUST install native connector for this extension to work. [...]
>
> For Ubuntu Linux package is available in the `ne0sight/chrome-gnome-shell` PPA. To install it, type:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ne0sight/chrome-gnome-shell 
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install chrome-gnome-shell
> ```

Comment: Yes, I did install that package. It should not affect Firefox though. Anyway, I could actually install some extension but the one I was trying to install from the beginning (namely LightDM Lock Screen, https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/910/lightdm-lock-screen) is still not installing

Comment: But it does. I have done it in my Firefox and it works now