# Some Keyboard shortcut become really slow

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

The keyboard shortcuts for opening terminal: <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> became really slow.
If i launch the program in a other way it work properly.

Comment: Are other desktop hotkeys, such as Volume Up slow as well? Ubuntu Utopic (if I remember correctly) had a bug that global desktop keys were often delayed by a few seconds, it was fixed in the next distro released. I've seen it happening once on Yakkety, logging out and back in (or rebooting, can't remember which) solved the issue. I don't know what the underlying problem is.

Comment: i don't have volume up and down on my keyboard.
but i happens sometimes with the printscreen  key, and sometimes it work correctly.
Actually my Ubuntu 16.04 was working correctly, but i was messing with some settings, i was installing some gnome extensions, i don't remember what i did before this happens, i tried to reinstall gnome-desktop , and remove all extension, but the problem haven't been solved.
I reset the gnome to default: http://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults 
and i doubt it's caused by this.

Comment: This question have the same problem and you can find a solution there: https://askubuntu.com/a/912250/586277

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Terminal appears with much delay when shortcut is used](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911946/terminal-appears-with-much-delay-when-shortcut-is-used)