# Why is FreeOffice's interface garbled?

Tags: gnome, vmware, interface

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10, GNOME. In a VMWare 14 Workstation VM. TextMaker and other FreeOffice apps are basically unusable because of this interface issue.

Aside from ONE test, and I'm not sure at all what might have been different in that test, it looks just as bad in KDE as it does in Gnome. I'm not sure if FreeOffice is based on GTK or QT but other QT apps look fine in Gnome and other GTK apps look fine in KDE. It's just this one thing, it seems.

I have also completed the steps in the accepted answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults) and the one below to entirely reset the gnome config to no avail.

Main toolbar example:
[image: Main toolbar example]

Tools menu example:
[image: Tools menu example]

Options dialog example:
[image: Options dialog example]

Comment: This looks like a corrupted font. Try a different theme(?)

Comment: That's a great thought but I have tried switching themes and fonts. I have also completed the steps in the accepted answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults) and the one below to entirely reset the gnome config. Then I tried a different user as well. It may be a theme/font issue but not one that I can fix by changing the font/theme or wiping settings.