# How to return back Ubuntu 18 default GNOME desktop?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, gnome-shell

After thousands Gnome Tweaks options changing and hundreds Extensions i want to return back my Desktop back to default view. I mean get back panel, dash, apps menu, hot corners and shortkeys.

Comment: If you create a new user and login as that user, is that desktop correct?

Comment: Doesn't [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults) work?

Comment: ^^ If this doesn't work, please edit the question to clarify and ping me.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible according to [this](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/08/restore-default-gnome-settings-in-ubuntu-quick-tip) article and the basic steps are as follows:

1. Log out of your session.
2. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> in unison.
3. Log in to your account at the prompt.
4. Run the following command very very very very very carefully: –

   ```
   mkdir gnome_backup; mv .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity gnome_backup/
   ```

   or if that doesn’t work

   ```
   rm .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity -rf
   ```
5. Return to the login screen by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

There are a number of caveats though as you will be initially logging out of your account so heed the advice and print out the detailed instructions before proceeding with caution.