# Restore GNOME desktop to original state

Tags: 18.04, gnome, desktop-environments

Cannot figure out how to get ubuntu desktop back to what it was before...

Problems:

- Right click only brings up "Change Background...", "Display Settings", and "Settings".  Before it would have a lot of options like like "create new file"...
- Side bar missing. I can only see it when I click on the activities...
- There is no Dock in the settings

[image: What my desktop looks like]

I would like to return desktop to its original state...

It used to look similar to this:
[image]

I tried looking at:

- [How to return back Ubuntu 18 default GNOME desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1141499/how-to-return-back-ubuntu-18-default-gnome-desktop)
- [How do I reset GNOME to the defaults?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults). I tried `rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity .cache .dbus .dmrc .mission-control .thumbnails ~/.config/dconf/user ~.compiz`

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: @K7AAY I do not have Unity installed on my system. I tried `Unity --reset` it says unity is not installed. I looked it up and it looks like gnome is the default desktop for Ubuntu 18.04 which is what I have.

Comment: you said your Unity bar was missing https://imgur.com/a/WcsJvjy ; having a Unity bar suggests you are using Unity. In your question above you tagged both Unity and GNOME. If you were using GNOME, what was the result when you tried the suggestions in  https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults ?

Comment: I tried to do `rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity .cache .dbus .dmrc .mission-control .thumbnails ~/.config/dconf/user ~.compiz*` No luck. Also, I changed the verbiage for clarification...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, install GNOME Tweaks as recommended by https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/03/how-to-reset-gnome-desktop-settings-to.html and [K. Monty](https://askubuntu.com/users/767047/k-monty); open a terminal, and run

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

then launch it, click on the upper panel at left on *Tweaks*, and choose *Reset to Defaults*. Then, logout and login again.

If that does not resolve the issue, then open a terminal and make a backup of [dconf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man7/dconf.7.html) settings recursively with [cp](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/cp.1.html)

```
md ~/dconf.bak && cp -r ~/.config/dconf/user ~/dconf.bak
```

Once the backup is made, tell dconf to reset to defaults

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/
```

Logout then login again. Check back with us if anything unusual occurs; we're here to help.

Comment: md: command not found

Comment: My tweaks does not have the "reset to defaults" option.