# Application issues only on my user after upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: gnome, upgrade

Finally did upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04.  After logging back in I've run into multiple issues.

I believe the issue is in my "gnome user profile".  Everything seems to work when logged in as different user.

I fixed some issues by deleting `~/.gconf` `~/.gnome` `~/.gnome2` like Nautilus not starting via dock icon and errors like.

- `g_key_file_load_from_file: assertion 'file != NULL' failed`
- `nautilus atk-bridge: get_device_events_reply: unknown signature`
- `nautilus Could not obtain desktop path or name`

But I'm still running into other little issues like

- Totem not playing videos. Application starts, but it's like on permanent pause.
- VLC no sound

I've tried all of the methods in [How do I reset GNOME to the defaults?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults) but the issue still persists.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: Try this: https://askubuntu.com/a/959976/480481 (and perhaps other answers too)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reset GNOME to the defaults?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults)

Comment: @pomsky - That seems to have brought all of my original problems back.

Answer (score 0):

Created a new user and manually bringing over data from old user to new.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/952353)

Comment: Looks like this was Brent Hansen's solution @Olimjon

Comment: @Zanna, my bad. :(