# Application List broken

Tags: desktop-apps

This was difficult to describe so I took some screenshots. The application list doesn't list all applications and also only lists a random number on 3 pages.

I can't add pictures to this post so please visit this link to see the images:
https://gucu.uk/ubuntu/ubuntu-21-04-application-list-broken/

I am running Ubuntu 21.04 and Gnome 3.38.5

Thanks

Rich

Comment: First disable any custom extensions, log out then back in to see whether it is not caused by an extension

Comment: Thanks for that. I disabled the extensions and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Disabling extensions didn't change anything.

Comment: You can reset all settings, which likely should solve the issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults/959976#959976 Then configure again to your liking.

Comment: Brilliant and thank you that sorted the problem.

Comment: Nice, I will add this as an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by an issue with your user configuration. It may be difficult to find the specific cause, but resetting Gnome settings may repair issues. You can do so as outlined in this [AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults/959976#959976) with the command

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/
```

That should restore your desktop to a default and working configuration, but will reset quite a bit: you will need to reconfigure some of your preferences after this.